# Populate entity from data array without form/request

Tags: php, symfony

Just wondering if it is possible to only use some parts of the symfony form handling. For exampe, when creating CRUD actions via `generate:doctrine:crud` I get something in my Controller (for handling create User POST requests) that looks like this:

```
$entity = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity,
        array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
));
$form->handleRequest($request);
//Here I have a filled Entity
```

But what I want is to have this in a more reusable solution. Currently I have my business logic in a service called `UserModel`. Here I also want to have the `create` method to create, validate and persist a new entity. Tough the `UserModel` should also be callable from some Command scripts via the console, so I probably won't always have `Request` nor a `Form`.

So now from the above code I know that Symfony is already somehow populating data to an Entity according to the `UserType` definition, but how could I do that manually without having a `Form` or a `Request` and instead just some array of data?
So that I don't have to take care of setting the properties myself.

**Edit:**
The validation is no issue for populating the entity, I'm using the `validator` later on the populated entity before persisting the data.
And also important for me would be that the passed `related entity ids` will be handled/loaded automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may still use the Form component, but instead of using `handleRequest`, you should use directly `submit`.

If you are curious, you should look up the code on github for both [`handleRequest`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L486-L491) and [what it actually does](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/NativeRequestHandler.php#L39) ; you'll see that it just do some verification, takes the data from the `Request`, and [then uses the `submit` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/NativeRequestHandler.php#L94) of the Form.

So, basically, you can use only the `submit` method with the data you wish to use. It even validates your entity. :)

**UPDATE**

And for the concern of creating / updating related entities, if your relation have a persist / update cascade, it should roll out from itself without you doing a single thing, except persist + flush on your main entity.

Comment: You are asking submit form in console??

Comment: It does not actually submit something from a Http request. It submits the "data" (which is actually an array of field => value) to fill up the targetted entity from the data

Comment: As stated on the other answer, yes I was actually thinking that the `Form` actually requires a `Request` and always uses some kind of Frontend.    
Tough if I look at it as some arbitrary "Data Form" that only MAY be used to create a HTML form or handle Requests but can also be used without those options, it actually should already handle all I need.     
Using the `submit` method to populate the data seem to work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not worry about handling validation like things, you can do something like I have done.

You can define a trait or include the **fromArray** function in your entity classes.

```
trait EntityHydrationMethod
{
    public function fromArray($data = array())
    {
        foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
            $method = "set{$property}";
            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you defined trait, you can use it in your entities like:

```
class User{

  use EntityHydrationMethod;

}
```

Then from your user model you can define your create function something like:

```
public function create($data = array())
{
    $entity = new User();
    $entity->fromArray($data);
    return $entity;
}
```

### -Updated-

As you updated your question. you may achieve this by defining a trait or include the **createFromArray** function in your EntityRepository classes.

```
trait RepositoryCreateMethod {
    public function createFromArray($data)
    {
        $class = $this->getClassName();

        $object = new $class();

        $meta = $this->getClassMetadata();

        foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
            $v = $value;

            if(!empty($value) && $meta->hasAssociation($property)) {
                $map = $meta->getAssociationMapping($property);
                $v = $this->_em->getRepository($map['targetEntity'])->find($value);
                if(empty($v)){
                    throw new \Exception('Associate data not found');
                }
            }

            $method = "set{$property}";
            $object->$method($v);
        }

        return $object;
    }
}
```

If you defined trait, you can use it in your Repository like:

```
class UserRepository{

  use RepositoryCreateMethod;

}
```

Then you can use this something like call from controller:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('YourBundle:User')
             ->createFromArray($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The validation is no problem here, I will validate after populating. But with this solution I would still have to take care about related entities myself. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: This is truly a dirty method to do it, it is not up to the entity to fill itself from an array, specially in a dynamic way (you may break everything)

Comment: Yea, I know that's not suggested method, but as @enricog mentioned, he doesn't bother about validation, its just a little idea that can be used to implement the needs.

Comment: Yeah but still, some setters may need specific objects, and if you feed from an array, even if it may be transformed later by the Form, it is still in a state which is probably not valid. You may trigger several 500s this way. Also, the input may also be different from what the output expects it to be (i.e snake_case converted to camelCase)... Which your methods doesn't respect at all. Hence my downvote.

Comment: @Talus: You may have missed the question. **enricog** wants to assign this from array. And thanks for point out the [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) +1 for that

Comment: **the input may also be different from what the output expects it to be (i.e snake_case converted to camelCase)** @Talus: I could not understand your this point. could you please explain?

Comment: With your method, if he puts something like `['property_snake_case' => 'foo', 'propertyCamel' => 'bar']`, it will generate a 500 if he does not have a `setProperty_snake_case` method, which he probably don't. The Form component (and to be more precise, the PropertyAccess component) deals with that, and knows how to map these things on his own

Comment: @Talus: Why he would not be?? As he Want to pass the data array, I think he will pass the valid array. You are missing another point of question, he isn't passing the array got from form submission.

Comment: What if he passes it from an API, which is just a request sent over Http ? I think what he wants to point out is that he need to fill up his entity, whichever the source is, from a set of data. Which may be comming from an http form, from a console command, from a POST request, from a fixture, ... etc. An unanimous way to do it from an api point of view. As he said, **he needs to be able to call his `UserModel` service as an api**.

Comment: On a subnote, I think you misinterpreted the true purpose of the form component. It is not actually "managing data from a http form", but more like "managing data through a submission of data", which is not only a http form, but can also be everything else (console command, post request, http form, ... etc)

Comment: :) Invalid form of data is invalid for any kind of source.. isn't it? This part of code is not sensitizing data. Here I am not writing whole application for someone, i guess. just suggestion solution for a specific problem. So assumption was valid data would be passed to the function. After all the function will not be called automatically. Thanks for explanation about form component.

Comment: @Talus yes thats actually it, I just want to pass data and get it filled (and if it also already gets validated, great). So actually I think I just misinterpreted the whole `Form` services by thinking the where mostly designed for using with HTML forms etc.
Edit: I will try your suggested solution by submitting the data directly via submit.