# Symfony2 Validating submitted data against Model class

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm trying to validate submitted data against existing Model/Entity/POPO, however I can't get it to work in any simple way.

All of this is takes place inside a controller action.

So, I can do like this:

```
    $constraints = new Assert\Collection([
        'username' => [new Assert\NotBlank()],
        'email' => [new Assert\Email()],
    ]);
    $violationList = $this->get('validator')->validate($request->request->all(), $constraints);
```

However to do that in every action makes no sense, as having all constraints in a class would be a lot better. So, Validation component allows to do like this:

```
// All constraints are defined inside Customer class
$customer = new Customer();
$violationList = $this->get('validator')->validate($customer);
```

Violation list is full of errors now, as $customer is an empty object, but the problem is I can't find a way to use data from POST AND validate it against constraints that are defined in the class.

It is possible to write extra component/helper that would take POST data and then will call bunch of `->setUsername()`, `->setEmail()`, etc., but that doesn't seem right considering you can easily map Model to POST data, if:

- Form component is involved;
- OR using ConstraintsCollection manually;

Am I missing something obvious here or there is no out-of-the-box possibility? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the form component is the one responsible for mapping post data to your entity. So you have two choices

1. Use a form,  like that you will have your data mapped and your model validated
2. Skip the form but then you have to map request params to your entity manually. then validate your model with `$this->get('validator')->validate($customer);`

**Edit :**

The form role is to map data coming from request ( html form , api .... ) to a model. Validation could be done with from or without it as its the `validator` component who does the job , it should be noted that the validation is done on the  model and not the form.

If you want to skip the form check this question: [Populate entity from data array without form/request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005809/populate-entity-from-data-array-without-form-request) although the form component is very useful specially if you are using the same logic in many places ( create / edit .. )

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid Form Component here. The data is not coming from the html form, so to me the usage of of FormComponent seems to be excessive with all the fields and their types definitions. Besides that each tool/component should be

Comment: Sorry, for double post - unfortunately I can't edit my comments, so I'll repeat myself a bit...
Besides that, each tool/component have its specific purpose, so using _Form_ in order just to do validation is not right.
_Validator_ already support syntax of `->validate($dataToValidate, $constraints);` so it seems kind of logical to be able to do the same against model class, especially as validating Model class in general is supported.